# When I try to load my game from my Main Menu I get an "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error but when loading in-game it works

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As the title outlines I get a object reference null error from main menu but not in-game. It currently happens on EquipGlasses() within the SaveLoadManager when loading from the main menu.

MainMenu Script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.HighDefinition;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;
using TMPro;

public class MainMenuManager : MonoBehaviour {
    int RandomInteger;
    [SerializeField] GameObject SkyboxObj;
    Volume SkyboxMap;

    [SerializeField]GameObject MainMenu;
    [SerializeField]GameObject OptionScreen;
    [SerializeField] GameObject LoadMenu;

    [SerializeField]Button ContnueBtn;
    [SerializeField]Button StartBtn;
    [SerializeField]Button OptionsBtn;
    [SerializeField]Button ExitBtn;

    [SerializeField]Slider AudioLevel;
    [SerializeField]InputField MouseSens;
    
    [SerializeField]VolumeProfile[] Skyboxes;
    
    [SerializeField]TMP_Text[] SaveDatesText = new TMP_Text[3];
    [SerializeField] Image[] Screenshots;

    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake() {
        RandomInteger = Random.Range (0, 4);
        SkyboxMap = SkyboxObj.GetComponent<Volume> ();
        SkyboxMap.profile = Skyboxes[RandomInteger];
        
    }

    void Start () {
        
        AudioLevel.value = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("AudioLevel", 0.5f);
        MouseSens.text = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("MouseSens", 1f).ToString ();
        
        StartBtn.onClick.AddListener (StartGame);
        OptionsBtn.onClick.AddListener (OptionsScreen);
        ExitBtn.onClick.AddListener (ExitGame);
        ContnueBtn.onClick.AddListener (Back2MainMenu);
    }

    public void OnClicked (GameObject SlotObj) {
        Debug.Log ("Checking save");
        switch (SlotObj.name) {
            case "Slot1":
                if (SaveLoadManager.instance.SavedSlotUsed[0]) {
                    Debug.Log ("Loading Save 1");
                    SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync ("Universal_Glasses").completed += (operation) => {
                        SaveLoadManager.instance.LoadGame (0);
                    };
                } else {
                    Debug.Log ("Beginning New Game");
                    SceneManager.LoadScene ("Universal_Glasses");
                }
                break;
            case "Slot2":
                if (SaveLoadManager.instance.SavedSlotUsed[1]) {
                    Debug.Log ("Loading Save 2");
                    SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync ("Universal_Glasses").completed += (operation) => {
                        SaveLoadManager.instance.LoadGame (1);
                    };
                }else {
                    Debug.Log ("Beginning New Game");
                    SceneManager.LoadScene ("Universal_Glasses");
                }
                break;
            case "Slot3":
                if (SaveLoadManager.instance.SavedSlotUsed[2]) {
                    Debug.Log ("Loading Save 3");
                    SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync ("Universal_Glasses").completed += (operation) => {
                        SaveLoadManager.instance.LoadGame (2);
                    };
                }else {
                    Debug.Log ("Beginning New Game");
                    SceneManager.LoadScene ("Universal_Glasses");
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    void StartGame () {
        //SceneManager.LoadScene ("Universal_Glasses");
        MainMenu.SetActive (false);
        LoadMenu.SetActive (true);
        
        for (int x = 0; x <SaveLoadManager.instance.SaveSlotCount; x++) {
            if (SaveLoadManager.instance.SavedSlotUsed[x]) {
                SaveDatesText[x].text = "Saved on: " +PlayerPrefs.GetString ("SaveSlot " + (x+1));
                Debug.Log (x);    
            } else if (SaveLoadManager.instance.SavedSlotUsed[x] != true) {
                SaveDatesText[x].text = "Slot " + (x + 1).ToString();
            }

        }

        LoadScreenshots ();
    }

    void OptionsScreen () {
        MainMenu.SetActive (false);
        OptionScreen.SetActive (true);
    }

    void Back2MainMenu () {
        OptionScreen.SetActive(false);
        MainMenu.SetActive (true);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("AudioLevel", AudioLevel.value);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("MouseSens", float.Parse (MouseSens.text));
    }
    

    void ExitGame () {
        Application.Quit ();
    }
    
    
    
    
    void LoadScreenshots()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < SaveLoadManager.instance.SaveSlotCount; i++)
        {
            string screenshotPath = SaveLoadManager.instance.GetScreenshotPath(i);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(screenshotPath))
            {
                LoadScreenshot(screenshotPath, i);
            }
        }
    }

    void LoadScreenshot(string screenshotPath, int index)
    {
        byte[] imageData = File.ReadAllBytes(screenshotPath);

        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
        if (texture.LoadImage(imageData))
        {
            Screenshots[index].sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), Vector2.zero);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to load screenshot at path: " + screenshotPath);
        }
    }
}
```

In-game Menu Script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public static UIManager instance;
    
    [SerializeField]bool TutDone;
    [SerializeField]GameObject TutoriallScreen;

    public bool GamePaused;
    [SerializeField] GameObject PauseMenu;
    [SerializeField] Button Resume;
    [SerializeField] Button Options;
    [SerializeField] Button MainMenuBtn;
    [SerializeField] Button Save_loadBtn;

    [SerializeField] GameObject Save_loadMenu;
    
    [SerializeField] GameObject OptionsMenu;
    [SerializeField] Button OpsResume;
    [SerializeField] Slider AudioLevel;
    [SerializeField] InputField MouseSens;

    public GameObject PopupTextObj;
    public TMP_Text PopupText;
    public GameObject InteractText;

    [SerializeField] GameObject GlassesMenu;
    private bool GlassesSelectActive;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() {

        instance = this;
        
        Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.timeScale * 0.01f;
        
        InteractText.SetActive (false);

        Resume.onClick.AddListener (ResumeGame);
        Options.onClick.AddListener (CallOptions);
        MainMenuBtn.onClick.AddListener (Back2Main);
        OpsResume.onClick.AddListener (Back2Esc);
        Save_loadBtn.onClick.AddListener (LoadSaveMenu);
        
        if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TutorialDone", 0) == 1) { //checks if the player has finished the tutorial, if they have they can continue
            TutDone = true;
            TutoriallScreen.SetActive (false);
            Time.timeScale = 1;
            GamePaused = false;
        } else {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("TutorialDone", 0);
            TutDone = false;
            Time.timeScale = 0;
            GamePaused = true;
        }
    }
    

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {

        if (TutDone == false && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0) && TutoriallScreen.activeSelf == true) { //if the tutorial is showing and the player presses left click the tutorial is the disabled permanently and the game continues
            TutDone = true;
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("TutorialDone", 1);
                TutoriallScreen.SetActive (false);
                Time.timeScale = 1;
                GamePaused = false;
        }

        if (GamePaused || GlassesSelectActive) {
            Cursor.visible = true;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Confined;

        } else if (!GamePaused || !GlassesSelectActive){
            Cursor.visible = false;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        }
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape) && TutDone == true) {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
            GamePaused = true;
            PauseMenu.SetActive (true);
        }

        
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Tab) && PauseMenu.activeSelf != true && OptionsMenu.activeSelf != true && DialogueManager.instance.DialoguePanel.activeSelf != true && TutDone == true) {
            Time.timeScale = 0.2f;
            GlassesSelectActive = true;           
            GlassesMenu.SetActive (true);
            Cursor.visible = true;
            GlassesSelectActive = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Tab)) {
            if (GameManager.instance.glassesinfo[GlassesSelectMenuScript.instance.Selection].Pickup == true) {
                GameManager.instance.x = GlassesSelectMenuScript.instance.Selection;
                GameManager.instance.EquipGlasses();
            }

            Time.timeScale = 1f;
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            GlassesSelectActive = false;
            GlassesMenu.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    public void OnSlotClick (GameObject SlotObj) {
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        switch (SlotObj.name) {
            case "Slot1":
                if (SaveLoadManager.instance.SavedSlotUsed[0] != true) {
                    SaveLoadManager.instance.SaveGame (0);
                } else {
                    SaveLoadManager.instance.LoadGame (0);
                }
                break;
            case "Slot2":
                if (SaveLoadManager.instance.SavedSlotUsed[1] != true) {
                    SaveLoadManager.instance.SaveGame (1);
                } else {
                    SaveLoadManager.instance.LoadGame (1);
                }
                break;
            case "Slot3":
                if (SaveLoadManager.instance.SavedSlotUsed[2] != true) {
                    SaveLoadManager.instance.SaveGame (2);
                } else {
                    SaveLoadManager.instance.LoadGame (2);
                }
                break;
        }
        Save_loadMenu.SetActive (false);
    }
    

    void FixedUpdate () {
        Time.fixedDeltaTime = Time.timeScale * 0.01f;
    }

    public void LoadSaveMenu () {
        OptionsMenu.SetActive (false);
        PauseMenu.SetActive (false);
        Save_loadMenu.SetActive (true);
    }

    public void ResumeGame () {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        PauseMenu.SetActive (false);
        GamePaused = false;

    }

    public void CallOptions () {
        AudioLevel.value = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("AudioLevel");
        MouseSens.text = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("MouseSens").ToString ();
        PauseMenu.SetActive (false);
        OptionsMenu.SetActive (true);
    }

    public void Back2Esc () {
        OptionsMenu.SetActive (false);
        PauseMenu.SetActive (true);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("AudioLevel", AudioLevel.value);
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("MouseSens", float.Parse (MouseSens.text));
    }

    public void Back2Main () {
        SceneManager.LoadScene ("Main Menu");
    }
    public IEnumerator WaitForDisable () {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (2f);
        PopupTextObj.SetActive (false);
    }
    
}
```

SaveLoadManager Script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

[System.Serializable]
public class SaveData {
    public string screenshotPath;
    public int currentEquippedPair;
    
    public float playerPosx;
    public float playerPosy;
    public float playerPosz;
    
    public float playerLookx;
    public float playerLooky;
    public float playerLookz;
    public float playerLookw;
    
    public bool[] unlockedPairs = new bool[4];

    public bool isSaving;
    public bool isLoading;
}

public class SaveLoadManager : MonoBehaviour {
    public static SaveLoadManager instance;
    public int SaveSlotCount = 3; //amount of saveslots
    string[] saveFilePaths; //array holding all save file pathways

    public bool[] SavedSlotUsed;

    private void Awake() {

        if (instance != null) {
            Debug.Log ("Found more than one Save/Load Manager in the scene. Destroying the newest one.");
            Destroy (this.gameObject);
            return;
        } else if (instance == null){
            Debug.Log ("Creating a new Save/Load Manager");
            instance = this;
        }
        
        saveFilePaths = new string[SaveSlotCount]; //used to create 3 saveslot strings
        
        for (int i = 0; i < SaveSlotCount; i++)
        {
            saveFilePaths[i] = Application.persistentDataPath + "/savegame_" + (i+1) + ".dat";
        }
        
        SavedSlotUsed = new bool [SaveSlotCount];
        for (int x = 0; x < SaveSlotCount; x++) {
            string prefKey = "SaveSlotUsed_" + (x +1);
            SavedSlotUsed[x] = PlayerPrefs.GetInt (prefKey, 0) == 1;
        }
        
        DontDestroyOnLoad (this.gameObject);
    }
    

    public void SaveGame(int saveSlot) {
        Debug.Log ("Saving to slot " + (saveSlot +1));
        if (saveSlot < 0 || saveSlot >= SaveSlotCount)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Invalid save slot: " + saveSlot);
            return;
        }

        SavedSlotUsed[saveSlot] = true;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < SaveSlotCount; i++)
        {
            string prefKey = "SaveSlotUsed_" + (i+1);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(prefKey, SavedSlotUsed[i] ? 1 : 0);
        }

        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        
        SaveData saveData = new SaveData();  //Lines 29 - 36 used to save needed data
        saveData.currentEquippedPair = GameManager.instance.x; //works great
        
        saveData.playerPosx = PlayerController.instance.currenPlayerPos.x;
        saveData.playerPosy = PlayerController.instance.currenPlayerPos.y;
        saveData.playerPosz = PlayerController.instance.currenPlayerPos.z;
        
        saveData.playerLookx = CameraController.instance.CurrentPlayerViewRotation.x;
        saveData.playerLooky = CameraController.instance.CurrentPlayerViewRotation.y;
        saveData.playerLookz = CameraController.instance.CurrentPlayerViewRotation.z;
        saveData.playerLookw = CameraController.instance.CurrentPlayerViewRotation.w;
        

         for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
             saveData.unlockedPairs[i] = GameManager.instance.glassesinfo[i].Pickup;
         }
        
        PlayerPrefs.SetString ("SaveSlot " + (saveSlot+1), DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"));

        // Generate a unique filename for the screenshot
        string screenshotFileName = "screenshot_" + (saveSlot+1) + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + ".png";

        // Construct the full save path for the screenshot
        string screenshotPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, screenshotFileName);

        // Take a screenshot and save it to the specified path
        ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(screenshotPath);

        // Save the screenshot path in the saveData object
        saveData.screenshotPath = screenshotPath;

        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream file = File.Create(saveFilePaths[saveSlot]);

        bf.Serialize(file, saveData);
        file.Close();
    }

    public void LoadGame(int saveSlot) {
        Debug.Log ("Loading from slot " + (saveSlot +1));
        if (saveSlot < 0 || saveSlot >= SaveSlotCount)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Invalid save slot: " + saveSlot);
            return;
        }

        if (File.Exists(saveFilePaths[saveSlot]))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(saveFilePaths[saveSlot], FileMode.Open);

            SaveData saveData = (SaveData)bf.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();

            // Use the saveData object to restore the game state
            float _playerPosx = saveData.playerPosx;
            float _playerPosy = saveData.playerPosy;
            float _playerPosz = saveData.playerPosz;
            
            int _currentEquippedPair = saveData.currentEquippedPair;
            
            float _playerLookx = saveData.playerLookx;
            float _playerLooky = saveData.playerLooky;
            float _playerLookz = saveData.playerLookz;
            float _playerLookw = saveData.playerLookw;
            // Restore other relevant fields from the saveData object
            {
                GameManager.instance.x = _currentEquippedPair;
                GameManager.instance.EquipGlasses ();
            
                PlayerController.instance.currenPlayerPos.x = _playerPosx;
                PlayerController.instance.currenPlayerPos.y = _playerPosy;
                PlayerController.instance.currenPlayerPos.z = _playerPosz;
                PlayerController.instance.CallOnLoad ();
            
                CameraController.instance.CurrentPlayerViewRotation.x = _playerLookx;
                CameraController.instance.CurrentPlayerViewRotation.y = _playerLooky;
                CameraController.instance.CurrentPlayerViewRotation.z = _playerLookz;
                CameraController.instance.CurrentPlayerViewRotation.w = _playerLookw;
                CameraController.instance.CallOnLoad ();
            
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    GameManager.instance.glassesinfo[i].Pickup = saveData.unlockedPairs[i];
                }
                
            } 
        }
    }
    

    public string GetScreenshotPath(int saveSlot)
    {
        if (saveSlot < 0 || saveSlot >= SaveSlotCount)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Invalid save slot: " + saveSlot);
            return null;
        }

        string screenshotPath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "screenshot_" + (saveSlot+1) + "_" + PlayerPrefs.GetString ("SaveSlot " + (saveSlot+1)) + ".png");
        return screenshotPath;
    }
    
}
```

I'm brand new to loading and saving to files so any help would be appreciated

As seen in the MainMenu script I tried `SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync ("Universal_Glasses").completed += (operation) =>` but that didn't function as expectd.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by playing around with my `instance = this` lines in my scripts and put them all in awake which fixed alot of my issues.